# Changing CSS property (left position) dynamically on setInterval

Tags: javascript, css, animation, setinterval

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I have a button. When this button is clicked - it fires a function which sets setInterval to run another function once a second. This function should move a divider 100 pixels to the left.

**What is actually occurring:**

The divider moves 100 pixels to the left but then stops and does not move on any subsequent firing on the setInterval function.

The image which fires the initial function:

```
<img id="playerimg" src="../../Downloads/1375889362_toggle-right_red.png" alt=""
width="42" height="42" border="0" onclick="vidgalshow()"/>
```

The statement inside this function which initializes and fires the Interval:

```
closemaindiv = setInterval("collapser()", 1000);
```

And finally the collapser function itself which should perform the animation:

```
document.getElementById("maindiv").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("maindiv").style.left = (document.getElementById("maindiv").style.left - 100);
```

I know that the Interval is firing every second because I have an alert() running each time. (But the box moves once to the left and then not again(!)).

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: `left` takes a *length* not an integer.

Comment: Not that it would fix anything, but I'd suggest using `setInterval(collapser, 1000)`. If you pass a string of script, it is executed in the global scope (and treated like an `eval` call, so it has those implications)...so if `collapser` were a local function, it wouldn't be found and would throw an exception. Just a general convention to follow

Comment: Thanks for these pointers guys. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to parse the current value as a number before subtracting:

```
var currentLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("maindiv").style.left, 10);
document.getElementById("maindiv").style.left = (currentLeft - 100) + "px";
```

Also, I recommend you pass a function reference to setInterval instead of a string:

```
closemaindiv = setInterval(collapser, 1000);
```